# Pandas: Compare column value with dictionary key and update values in the new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to compare the dictionary "key" with pandas column and based on that insert dictionary "value" into the new column.

**Example:**

```
sample_dict = {'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2':'c'}

Sample_df = 

        col_1  
0         0         
1         1         
2         0         
3         1         
4         0
```

I want to create a new column "col_2" if the dictionary's `key` value matches with `col_1`

```
        col_1     col_2
0         0         a
1         1         b
2         0         a
3         1         b
4         2         c
```

What's the best way to do the comparison and have the value in the new column.

**Existing Code:**

```
for key in request.POST:
    df['col_2'] = pd.np.where(df.col_1.astype(str).str.contains(key), request.POST[key])
```

where request.POST is a querySET (dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using `map`

```
df['col_2']=df.col_1.astype(str).map(sample_dict)
#df.col_1.astype(str).map(sample_dict)
Out[757]: 
0    a
1    b
2    a
3    b
4    a
Name: col_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting following error: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Give me some time, I think I am having it inside the loop to parse. Maybe I need to remove the loop...

Comment: My apologies, my dictionary values are in list format: 'exampleRadios_0': ['0'], 'exampleRadios_1': ['0'], 'exampleRadios_2': ['0'], 'exampleRadios_3': ['0'], 'exampleRadios_4': ['0'], 'exampleRadios_5': ['0'], 'exampleRadios_6': ['0'], 'exampleRadios_7': ['0']

Comment: Hey, it worked directly without making any modifications with the value type. Thank you